# In token-based authentication how do tokens get verified?

Tags: web-services, authentication, jwt

I've read numerous token based authentication articles and they typically fail to explain how the server verifies token. I understand that:

1. User Requests Access with Username / Password
2. Application validates credentials
3. Application provides a signed token to the client
4. Client stores that token and sends it along with every request
5. Server verifies token and responds with data

But how does step 5 specifically happen?

Comment: Since the server provided the token in the 1st place, it already knows if the token is valid or not, and who it belongs to.

Comment: How? Does the server store it somewhere and then compares the token on each request?

Comment: Of course, that is the whole point.

Comment: I guess I don't have any technical info on how it does store it. Does it store it in like an in mem db or is the implementation up to you as an engineer? Can any one point me to good info about this?

Comment: @PradeepPati  You probably shouldn't have said "Of course," since you are wrong.  The server does not store the token on its server and then compare it on each request.  That would take too much database storage across users.  It simply stores the secret key used for signing.  It can then take the header + '.' + payload that it received, and sign that using the secret key it has, then compare the signatures.  If the signature matches, then it trusts the payload.  Six six six asked a good question and is showing a heart to learn.  Don't belittle his question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token-based authentication terminology can be used in a few contexts so the answer will always depend on the exact question. You did tag your question with JWT ([JSON Web Tokens](https://auth0.com/learn/json-web-tokens/)) so I'll answer this by drawing a few assumptions based on that tag.

> JSON Web Token (JWT) is an open standard ([RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519)) that defines a compact and **self-contained way** for securely **transmitting information** between parties as a JSON object. This information **can be verified and trusted because it is digitally signed**. JWTs can be signed using a secret (with HMAC algorithm) or a public/private key pair using RSA.

(emphasis is mine, source: see link above)

This definition sheds some light on your exact question on how a server application verifies a token. It does it, in the case of a JWT, by checking if the associated digital signature is valid; it actually does more than just checking the signature, but this is the most important step.

> **Digital Signature**: A cryptographic method for ascertaining whether or not a digital message or set of documents is genuine, has not been altered or tampered with in transit, and comes from a known sender.

(source: [Auth0 Identity Glossary](https://auth0.com/identity-glossary))

You can digitally sign something by applying different algorithms, but this process can be described at a very high-level to consist of the following:

- Select a secret that only you (your server) will know about.
- Pass the secret and data to be signed to a given algorithm.

The output will consist of a signature that can then be later used to check (if you also know the secret) if some data is exactly equal to the one that originally produced the signature.

In conclusion a server generates a JWT which is signed, distributed to any client application and **as long as the server ensures the secret used to sign it is known to no one else** it can ensure that the received tokens were not tampered with and were in fact issued by a trusted party.

As mentioned before, the server besides checking the signature can do further validations, usually it will at least also validate that the token is still valid in terms of lifetime. This is recommended because this authentication process that relies purely on having a token, usually referred to as a bearer token, means that if an attacker is able to get hold of a token it can only use it within is configured lifetime. A derived recommendation is that the lifetime of bearer tokens should also be relatively short.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. The token can be a hash of the username the password and a key that the client generates, it can be just random and stored in a db, there is not a unique answer for this